# How to set transaction isolation per request using Hibernate + Dropwizard + Guice for DI and Spring Data JPA?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, guice, dropwizard

How, without using Spring as the DI framework (as it offers the `@Transactional` annotation offering custom isolation level for that transaction), could I have **simple** custom isolation level for specific/sensible transaction in a web service built on Dropwizard + Hibernate + Guice (DI) + Spring Data JPA + PostgreSQL (all recent versions)?

Here's a simple working example of web service with the exact same stack (pull requests are more than welcome):
https://github.com/jeep87c/dropwizard-guice-springDataJPA-hibernate

We use Spring Data JPA as an abstraction layer above Hibernate to simply save us from writing our own implementation for each DAOs. In an ideal world, it would be the only dependency to Spring for the web service but as you'll see in this code sample, we are doing kind of a hack by resolving the DAO implementation with Spring DI framework (using the `beanFactory`) so we can then register these in Guice. (I'm more than open to a better solution if you have one but this is not the subject of this question)

In this code sample, `AbsenceResource.create` voluntary perform a dup persist of the payload received. And there's an acceptance test `AbsenceResourceAcceptanceTest.rollbackTest` testing this compromised API route expecting the rollback to happen.

The business requirement here is, to create a new absence, it must first verify if no other absences collide with this one for the same employee in the same company. The sample repo I provide is actually simpler than my real life scenario where actually it must verify collision with absences and vacations entities for an employee in a multi-tenant (per company) environnement having a single table per entity (multi-tenancy with column filtering on the company id).

To prevent any concurrency issue resulting in the race condition that would let two colliding absences be wrongly inserted, we would like to set the isolation level to *Serializable* for this kind of specific transaction as per [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE) reveals to be the only choice to avoid such kind of issue.

We looked into [dropwizard-hibernate](https://www.dropwizard.io/en/stable/manual/hibernate.html) library but unfortunately, it doesn't provide any way to set the isolation level per transaction.

So before I spend hours replacing Guice by Spring as our DI framework in our web service (as it looks like the only option for now), I'm seeking other potential simple solutions that would achieve the same.

Comment: The simplest and crudest thing I could think of is issuing the [corresponding SQL statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-set-transaction.html).

Comment: Is it PostgreSQL specific or it is regular SQL?

Comment: To be honest, the more I look into this the more I'm getting to the point that fully using Spring is the best and easiest solution...

Comment: Maybe using [hibernate optimistic locking](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#locking-optimistic) directly on my entities... But I'm no expert on this part of Hibernate

Comment: According to the [official PostgreSQL docs `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` IS part of the SQL standard](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/features-sql-standard.html). Search for `E152-01`.

Comment: Even simpler: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setTransactionIsolation-int-